# Excel Find and Replace with Formulas - No VBA

Tags: excel, formulas

I am curious if I can exploit the "find and replace" dialogue in Excel to perform the following task:

Excel formula in cell B1:

```
=myVBAFunction(A1)
```

Needs to change to

```
=myVBAFunction(A1)+F1
```

This is easy with Find And Replace as I simply find "myVBAFunction(A1)" and replace with "myVBAFunction(A1)+F1". However I need to repeat this process for B2 which references A2 and F2. Then for B3 and so on.

Many people suggest dragging down the formula which is great, or I could adjust my function to incorporate the extra functionality. No need for Stackoverflow...

**Here's the catch** I can't use VBA and the dragging down won't work as I'm relying on the less-tech savvy user doing this in a failsafe way. The find and replace method would be the most reliable.

The user I'm instructing could do find and replace (a real example has multiple sheets) but I can't rely on them to find the cell and drag down the formula.

Yes I could email a new version but I'm curious if this can actually be done in a find and replace style way (or other equally simple)?

Comment: So is the issue that the `A1` reference inside the VBA function call `myVBAFunction(A1)` doesn't update as you drag and drop?

Comment: Please show us some more data so it is clear what the transformation actually is.

Comment: ^^ As per Tim's comment. Are you only modifying existing formulas or is there also some sort of "autofill" element?

Comment: No dragging allowed - see my own answer but the problem was finding one line of generic replace text that would ensure that the cell references were automatically generated or self-calculating. INDIRECT and ROW did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question - INDIRECT has saved  the day.

Quest - replace contents of A1 with

```
=myVBAFunction(B1)
```

with

```
=myVBAFunction(B1)+F1
```

Without using VBA, or dragging down the formula so that the method results with A1000 referencing B1000 and F1000 etc.

You can use Find & Replace like this

REPLACE with

=myVBAFunction(INDIRECT("B" & ROW())) + INDIRECT("F" & ROW())

Using INDIRECT and ROW allows the same replace text for every cell, but the referencing to work post replace.